# How can you tell if a file was removed from Google Drive using their API?

Tags: go, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API v3 and the Go SDK to monitor new and removed files on my drive.  I've looked over the [Google Drive API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files) and they provide 2 file properties that seem like they would allow one to determine if a file was deleted.

1. Changes.File.Trashed
2. Changes.File.ExplicitlyTrashed

After I remove the file, the file appears in the change list, but both properties are false.

**What attribute, service, or call can I use to determine if something has been removed?**

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "google.golang.org/api/drive/v3"
)

func main() {

    // More code is required to setup the service, but I didn't include it.
    srv := new(drive.Service)

    //......

    token, _ := srv.Changes.GetStartPageToken().Do()

    // ..... some time passes

    // I right click file and select "Remove" from google drive using web app.
    // Now I list any changes in MyDrive

    changes, _ := srv.Changes.List(token.StartPageToken).IncludeRemoved(false).RestrictToMyDrive(true).Do()

    for _, c := range changes.Changes {
        fmt.Println("File name: " + c.File.Name) // I get the expected file name
        fmt.Println("Trash: " + strconv.FormatBool(c.File.Trashed)) //false
        fmt.Println("Removed: " + strconv.FormatBool(c.Removed)) //false
        fmt.Println("ExplicitlyTrashed: " + strconv.FormatBool(c.File.ExplicitlyTrashed)) //false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `IncludeRemoved` to true and `RestrictToMyDrive` to false - at least while you're investigating this missing changes problem. The doc says:

> includeRemoved    boolean Whether to include changes indicating that items have left the view of the changes list, for example by deletion or lost access. (Default: true)

and

> restrictToMyDrive boolean Whether to restrict the results to changes inside the My Drive hierarchy. This omits changes to files such as those in the Application Data folder or shared files which have not been added to My Drive. (Default: false)

Edit 10 Dec: Your issue is caused by the fact that if the file is trashed then the change resource will NOT contain a file resource. You should check the change resource for the `removed` flag and not check for any file properties because the file resource won't be there in the change:

> removed    boolean Whether the file has been removed from the view of the changes list, for example by deletion or lost access.
>
> file   nested object   The updated state of the file. *Present if the file has not been removed.*

The info above is from the [Drive V3 reference guide > changes page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes#resource)

Comment: I've done something similar before, but I wanted to try again at your suggestion.  I just did and I'm still getting false across the board.

Comment: If I list the files in the folder like so `fs, err := s.srv.Files.List().PageSize(100).Fields("files(id, name, trashed)").Q(query).Do()` then the trash field gets populated.  If I leave `trashed` off then it's always false.  I tried the same thing on my Changes call and it errors out saying `Error 400: Invalid field selection files, invalidParameter`.  BTW, `query` is `'folderid' in parents`

Comment: It would be clearer for me (and others that come by) if you updated the question with the current code and fail state.